# What is this early D&D or AD&D image of a rogue-type leaping into two-weapon combat?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, content-identification, art

I am looking for an image that I remember from early D&D or AD&D artist of a roguish-type human (maybe a Halfling) jumping into combat with two weapons in hand.  It could have been from a module or supplement, I am not sure.  It is not the one of the fat Halfling jumping from a tree.  It was more old school, like Jeff Dee or David C Sutherland III... Maybe Bill Willingham (maybe none of these guys, but similar style).  I cannot seem to locate it anywhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a time range for when you could have seen it, or when this book might have been published? Was it colour or black & white (or not sure)? Painted or line art? Cartoonish or realistic? What angle was the character seen from? Anything else visible in the frame, or just the character? Anything more you can remember helps.

Comment: And some more: Pencil (grescale) or Ink? Movement lines or not?

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you have any answers to SevenSidedDie's questions, you should use the [edit] link here or at the bottom of your question to include those details in the question itself.

Comment: Just adding *which 2 weapons* the dude (?) is armed with would be a big a help, narrowing this to all those illustrations of rogues leaping into combat with two crossbows, two maces, or two halberds, for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an image that *may* be associated with an RPG, rather than being about RPGs.